# select2 changing items dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I have two selects that are linked: Each value of the first select determines which items will be displayed in the second select.

The values of the second select are stored in a two-dimension array:

```
[ [{"id":1,"text":"a"}, {"id":2,"text":"b"},...],
  [{"id":"1a","text":"aa"},{"id":"1b","text":"ba"},...],
  ...
]
```

The first select value determines the index to be used to populate the second select. So in a 'change' event on the first I should be able to modify the items select-two contains.

Reading documentation I think I need to use the "data" option... but not shure how as the example loads the array data on initialization and it seems to don't work if I try to do the same after initialization.

**HTML**

```
Attribute:
<select name="attribute" id="attribute">
    <option value="0">Color</option>
    <option value="1">Size</option>
</select>

Value:
<select name="value" id="value"></select>

<script>
   var data = [ [{"id":1,"text":"black"}, {"id":2,"text":"blue"},...],
                [{"id":"1","text":"9"},{"id":"1","text":"10"},...],
              ];
   $('#attribute').select2().bind('change', function(){
      // Here I need to change `#value` items.
      $('#value').select2('data',data[$(this).val()]);  // This does not work
   );

   $('#value').select2();
</script>
```

Comment: Show us the code you have already.

Comment: Example added, In the comment I tried the $('#value').select2('data',data[$(this).val()]);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16480910/update-select2-data-without-rebuilding-the-control

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I've made an example for you showing how this could be done.

Notice the js but also that I changed #value into an input element

```
<input id="value" type="hidden" style="width:300px"/>
```

and that I am triggering the `change` event for getting the initial values

```
$('#attribute').select2().on('change', function() {
    $('#value').select2({data:data[$(this).val()]});
}).trigger('change');
```

[**Code Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/bbAU9/)

**Edit:**

In the current version of select2 the class attribute is being transferred from the hidden input into the root element created by select2, even the `select2-offscreen` class which positions the element way outside the page limits.

To fix this problem all that's needed is to add `removeClass('select2-offscreen')` before applying select2 a second time on the same element.

```
$('#attribute').select2().on('change', function() {
    $('#value').removeClass('select2-offscreen').select2({data:data[$(this).val()]});
}).trigger('change');
```

I've added a new **[Code Example](http://jsfiddle.net/eGXPe/)** to address this issue.

Comment: Simply updating your jsfiddle to current select2 and jquery sources breaks it. (http://jsfiddle.net/pFY9Z/) Do you have an example that would work with the current versions?

Comment: Why does this not work with multiple select inputs using the same data set? ([http://jsfiddle.net/eGXPe/58/](http://jsfiddle.net/eGXPe/58/))

Comment: If you set `allowClear: true` on dynamically updated select2 fields, the clear button is never enabled.(http://jsfiddle.net/eGXPe/116/) Any ideas how to get about this?

Comment: From the official documentation: "This option only works when the placeholder is specified". This should do it: http://jsfiddle.net/eGXPe/117/ and I've also fixed a minor bug by reseting the value of the second select box whenever the data list changes.

Answer (score 37):

I'm successfully using the following to update options dynamically:

`$control.select2('destroy').empty().select2({data: [{id: 1, text: 'new text'}]});`

Comment: One problem I encountered with this is answer is that it will overwrite the empty option/placeholder.

Comment: it does not work if you have initially set your data in html tag with "data-data="

Answer (score 11):

Try using the trigger property for this:

```
$('select').select2().trigger('change');
```

Comment: Please explain what this does and why it answers the question.

Comment: first assign new value to `select` and then `trigger` change like 
     `$('select').select2().trigger('change');
$('select').select2().trigger('change');`

Answer (score 7):

I fix the lack of example's library here:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.js">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bbAU9/328/

Answer (score 4):

For v4 this is a known issue that won't be addressed in 4.0 but there is a workaround. Check https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2830

Answer (score 4):

In my project I use following code:

```
$('#attribute').select2();
$('#attribute').bind('change', function(){
    var $options = $();
    for (var i in data) {
        $options = $options.add(
            $('<option>').attr('value', data[i].id).html(data[i].text)
        );
    }
    $('#value').html($options).trigger('change');
});
```

Try to comment out the select2 part. The rest of the code will still work.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = [
    {
        id: 0,
        text: 'enhancement'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'bug'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: 'duplicate'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: 'invalid'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text: 'wontfix'
    }
];

$('#attribute').select2({
    data: data
});

$("#attribute").select2().val(1).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking a code that is changing another dropdown data by fetching data from server side(Api). You should try this one.

```
$('#attribute').on('change', function (e) {
        $.post("../api", { id: e.val }).done(resp => {
            $("#value").select2('destroy').empty();
            resp.map(o => $("#value").append("<option value=\"" + o.Value + "\">" + o.Text + "</option>"));
            $("#value").select2();
        });
    });
```