# Select2 dynamic data setting

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I am trying to use select2 with jQuery 1.9.1 and select2 3.3.0 to implement what I imagine is a fairly basic use case...I want to populate a select2 control with options based on the state of another select2 control.

I have the following:

```
<div>
  <select id="master" name="master">
    <option value=1>a</option>
    <option value=2>b</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="hidden" id="detail" name="detail" data-placeholder="No options until master chosen">
  </select>

<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="select2-3.3.0/select2.js"></script>
<script>
var a = [];
var b = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  a.push({id: i, text: "a" + i});
  b.push({id: i, text: "b"+ i});
}

$(document).ready( function () {
  $("#master").select2().on('change', function() {
    console.log("master changed: " + $("#master").val())
    var right_one = a;
    if($("#master").val() == 2) right_one = b;
    $("#detail").removeClass('select2-offscreen').select2({data:right_one})
    console.log("right_one: " + right_one)
  })


})
```

**Edit:**
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13269663/264788) shows why the control was disappearing. I have questions remaining regarding this implementation:

1. How can I make #master *not* have an initial selection?
2. How can I change the placeholder text in #detail so that it
   responds to the fact that a master has been chosen?

Answer (score 1):

the second select #detail will not work anymore, you can only click on options, but if you try typing few chars you'll see what's happen.

Answer (score 0):

Mabye something like this:

```
<script>
var a = [];
var b = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  a.push({id: i, text: "a" + i});
  b.push({id: i, text: "b"+ i});
}

$(document).ready( function () {
    //set up default data, should work without one too
    $('#detail').data('select2_values', []);
    $('#detail').select2({
        allowClear: true,
        width: '150px',
        placeholder: 'No options until master chosen',
        query: function (query) {
            var data = {results: []};
            if (query.term == '')
            {
                data.results = $('#detail').data('select2_values');
            }
            query.callback(data);
        },
        initSelection : function (element, callback) {
            var data = $(element).data('select2_values');
            if (typeof(data)!='object') data = [];
            callback(data);
        },
        data: $(this).data('select2_values')
    }).select2('disable');
    $('#master').select2({
        allowClear: true,
        width: '150px'
    }).on("change", function(e) {
        var right_one = a;
        if ($('#master').select2('val') == 2) right_one = b;
        $("#detail").data('select2_values', right_one);

        //Remove previous value if any
            $("#detail").select2('val','');

        //If you want to select some vaoue you can use next line
        //$("#detail").select2('data', right_one[0]);

        //Enable 2nd box
        $("#detail").select2('enable');
    });
});

</script>
```

Tested on chrome+win32