# JavaScript: How to pass multiple arguments to a callback function inside an object's member?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

When working with plugins I sometimes stumble upon one that has something like this:

- It will take constructor arguments.
- Some of the parameters resolve to functions.
- Some of those will take multiple arguements.

like this:

```
{
    color: function (someData, moreData) {
        return someData + moreData;
    }
}
```

**How do I pass two arguments to that function?**

Note: I am unable to change the plugin, so moving the second argument to another constructor argument is not an option.

Sample JavaScript:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.greenify = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            color: function (someData, moreData) { // <-- THIS TAKES 2 ARGUMENTS!
                return someData + moreData;
            },
        }, options);
        return this.css({
            color: settings.color,
        });
    };
}(jQuery));

$("#target1").greenify({
    color: "blue"
});

$("#target2").greenify({
    color: ["bl", "ue"]   // <-- In your answer only this should be changed
});
```

My targets:

```
<div id="target1">My Thing</div>   // <-- will be blue
<div id="target2">My Thing2</div>  // <-- will be black but should be blue
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JnME3/)

---

**UPDATE:**
I fell for a major misconception that this code

```
$("#target1").greenify({
    color: "blue"
});
```

would hand the value `"blue"` over to `function (someData, moreData)` as first parameter `someData`. ***This is false!*** What actually happens is that the default callback (`function (someData, moreData)`) is completely replaced by the string `"blue"`!

Comment: You actually don't have to change the constructor ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/daktx/)), but you'll have to update the plugin body anyway, I suppose.

Comment: I guess you didn't show us the actual plugin since what you posted doesn't make much sense (but may be a fault of the plugin coder). If so, please link to the real source code.

Comment: @Bergi: [Here is the actual plugin](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/blob/master/select2.js#L2239) which rose this question to me. But my question is not about a design decision. I am curious as of the capabilities of JS.

Comment: The relevant line is [here](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/blob/a4a3eedd51f0379b15e8f650bcc91982c64c37f4/select2.js#L3041) - it calls the method with the given name with multiple arguments (e.g. `$(…).select2("data", someValues, true)`). Is that what you wanted? Or do you want to know more about *how* to design jQuery plugins and about using `.apply`?

Comment: Thank you. This is a good solution to the initial problem. Aside from that I am still curious about ways to handle the above sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I pass two arguments to that function?

You don't. jQuery does. It's a callback function to determine the `color` property dynamically in the `.css()` method - see [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-functionindex--value).

So actually, that default function doesn't make any sense as it should return a css color value but returns the old value prefixed by the index of the element - which is definitely not a color.

So just use `$("#target2").greenify({color: "black"})`.

If you want to pass a function, that is also possible - but it will overwrite, not call that default function. An example:

```
$("div").greenify({
    color: function(index, prevColor) {
        return ["blue", "black"][index % 2];
    }
});
```

Comment: Will this actually override the `function (someData, moreData) {...}` or will it only pass it's return value to the first argument `someData` in the original function?

Comment: Yes, it will replace it on the `settings` object. It's impossible to call that function as you cannot access it from outside (without using some ugly hacks, like compromising `$.extend`)

Comment: I'll accept this as the answer as this is the closest fit (pointing at the last part) - basically the question incorporates a design flaw, that no plugin will actually ever have.

Answer (score 0):

```
var settings = $.extend({}, options);
if($.isArray(options.color)) {
    settings.color = function () {
        return options.color.join('');
    };
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2QBGm/

Comment: OP said he is unable to change the plugin!

Answer (score 0):

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JnME3/5/)

I have made some changes to your code and it's now working as you want it.

I used the options object to get the arguments:

```
color: function () {
    return options.color[0] + options.color[1];
}
```

Comment: OP said he is unable to change the plugin!

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the notice. I thought plugin is something else. I didn't understand the question fully. My bad, sorry