# Reload div with Select2 field using Ajax or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have two ajax forms loaded in a bootstrap modal.

The first form is for creating a contact (just a name input field).

The second form is for creating a patient record with multiple fields. One of the fields is a select2 field, on which you can select who recommended that patient. The options of this select2 field is all the contacts in the database.

**I try to achieve the below:**

Every time i submit a new contact on the first form i would like to reload the div containing the select2 field on the second form so that i can select the submitted contact.

I have managed to reload the select field when it's not using select2 but when i try my code with a select2 field the field disappear.

Below you can see my code.

**Contact Creation Form:**

```html
<form id="newcon" role="form" class="form-horizontal form-groups-bordered validate" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?admin/contact/fastcreate" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="field-1" class="reqlbl col-sm-3 control-label">
      <?php echo get_phrase( 'name'); ?>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="field-1" data-validate="required" data-message-required="<?php echo get_phrase('value_required');?>">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="field-20" class="reqlbl col-sm-3 control-label">
      <?php echo get_phrase( 'last_name'); ?>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" id="field-20" data-validate="required" data-message-required="<?php echo get_phrase('value_required');?>">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 control-label col-sm-offset-2">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-success dis" value="<?php echo get_phrase('create_contact');?>" onclick="this.value='<?php echo get_phrase('sending_please_wait')?>...';">
  </div>
</form>
```

**Patient Creation Form**

```html
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal form-groups-bordered validate" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php?admin/patient/create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group selectcontactreload">
    <label for="field-ta" class="col-sm-3 control-label">
      <?php echo get_phrase( 'recommendation'); ?>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <select id="selectcontact" name="sistasi" class="form-control select2">
        <option value="">
          <?php echo get_phrase( 'select_contact'); ?>
        </option>
        <option value="newcontact">
          <?php echo get_phrase ( 'new_contact') ?>
        </option>
        <?php foreach ($contact_info as $row) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['contact_id']; ?>">
          <?php echo $row[ 'name'] . ' ' . $row[ 'last_name']; ?>
        </option>
        <?php } ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="field-2" class="reqlbl col-sm-3 control-label">
      <?php echo get_phrase( 'name'); ?>
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="field-2" data-validate="required" data-message-required="<?php echo get_phrase('value_required');?>">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 control-label col-sm-offset-2">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="<?php echo get_phrase('submit');?>">
  </div>
</form>
```

**The code i tried to reload the select2 field on the first form submission is the below:**

```js
$('#newcon').ajaxForm(function() {

  $(".selectcontactreload").load('index.php?modal/popup/add_patient' + " .selectcontactreload");

});
```

The problem with the above code is that it reloads the field but without triggering the select2 js. 
If i remove the select2 class from the select field it works perfectly but i need it to work with select2.

Any suggestions? 
I have seen other posts that says to use the below:

```js
$('#newcon').ajaxForm(function() {

$("#selectcontact").select2("destroy");
$("#selectcontact").select2();

});
```

but this code doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Did you see the console for any errors? You can see the console by pressing `F12`.

Comment: Reload Select2 like explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818210/how-to-refresh-select2-dropdown-menu-after-ajax-loading-different-content

Comment: Yes i have checked, no errors. When i check the html from firebug i can see the select field with the new submitted data but it is not visible. You can see here [link](http://demo.onmedoffice.com/select.jpg)

Comment: Tanrikut thank but i have seen this post and it doesn't solve my problem
I have tried    
$("#selectcontact").select2("destroy");
$("#selectcontact").select2(); 
with no luck

Comment: Praveen Kumar i dont believe this is a duplicate post since the post you mention doesnt solve my problem.. Please show some understanding. Thank you