# jquery option select filter by other option select

Tags: jquery, html

I want, if I select "Mammals", the animals select option only show option data-animal_class with value 1.

I know how to get the Mammals value, but I'm confused as to how to use filter

This is my code:

```js
$('#class').on('change', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var animal = $(this).val();
  console.log(animal);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="class">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">Mammals</option>
  <option value="2">Birds</option>
  <option value="3">Reptiles</option>
</select>

<select id="animals">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="11" data-animal_class="1">Cow</option>
  <option value="12" data-animal_class="1">Sheep</option>
  <option value="13" data-animal_class="1">Bear</option>
  <option value="21" data-animal_class="2">Parrot</option>
  <option value="22" data-animal_class="2">Pigeons</option>
  <option value="23" data-animal_class="2">Bear</option>
  <option value="31" data-animal_class="3">Crocodile</option>
  <option value="32" data-animal_class="3">Lizard</option>
  <option value="33" data-animal_class="3">Turtle</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why `e.preventDefault();` ? That does not seem applicable here

Comment: Check the answers from [here](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=jquery+dependent+dropdown&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIN793IN793&oq=jquery+dependenct+dr&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.10910j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: thanks, iam very newbie using jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use `filter()` you can provide a function which compares the given `animal` value against the `data-animal_class` and returns `true` when there is a match. From there you can hide/show the relevant options, like this:

```js
var $options = $('#animals option');

$('#class').on('change', function() {
  var animal = $(this).val();
  if (animal == '') {
    $options.show();
  } else {  
    $options.hide().filter(function() {
      return $(this).data('animal_class') == animal;
    }).show();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="class">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">Mammals</option>
  <option value="2">Birds</option>
  <option value="3">Reptiles</option>
</select>

<select id="animals">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="11" data-animal_class="1">Cow</option>
  <option value="12" data-animal_class="1">Sheep</option>
  <option value="13" data-animal_class="1">Bear</option>
  <option value="21" data-animal_class="2">Parrot</option>
  <option value="22" data-animal_class="2">Pigeons</option>
  <option value="23" data-animal_class="2">Bear</option>
  <option value="31" data-animal_class="3">Crocodile</option>
  <option value="32" data-animal_class="3">Lizard</option>
  <option value="33" data-animal_class="3">Turtle</option>
</select>
```

Comment: your code work for me, but i need to delete $('.select2').select2(); , can you help me to fix this?

Comment: Using Select2 is an important distinction with a standard `select` control which you should have mentioned in the question. I would suggest starting a new question about that

Answer (score 1):

you can try below logic where you can show/hide animal options on change event of class select box. You can use attribute selector to show/hide options

```js
$(function(){
  $('#class').on("change", function(){
    $("#animals option").hide();
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value) {
       $("#animals option[data-animal_class=" + value + "]").show();
    }
      $("#animals").val(""); 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="class">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="1">Mammals</option>
   <option value="2">Birds</option>
   <option value="3">Reptiles</option>
</select>

<select id="animals">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="11" data-animal_class="1">Cow</option>
   <option value="12" data-animal_class="1">Sheep</option>
   <option value="13" data-animal_class="1">Bear</option>
   <option value="21" data-animal_class="2">Parrot</option>
   <option value="22" data-animal_class="2">Pigeons</option>
   <option value="23" data-animal_class="2">Bear</option>
   <option value="31" data-animal_class="3">Crocodile</option>
   <option value="32" data-animal_class="3">Lizard</option>
   <option value="33" data-animal_class="3">Turtle</option>
</select>
```

Comment: your code work for me, but i need to delete $('.select2').select2(); , how to fix this?

Comment: have you try to refresh select? see for your reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818210/how-to-refresh-select2-dropdown-menu-after-ajax-loading-different-content

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version

```js
$('#animalClass').on('change', function(e) {
  var animal = $(this).val();
  $("#animals option").each(function() { 
     var show = $(this).attr("value").indexOf(animal)==0;
//  $(this).prop("disabled",!show); // disable OR
    $(this).toggle(show); // toggle
  })
}).change(); // run at load
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="animalClass">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">Mammals</option>
  <option value="2">Birds</option>
  <option value="3">Reptiles</option>
</select>

<select id="animals">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="11" data-animal_class="1">Cow</option>
  <option value="12" data-animal_class="1">Sheep</option>
  <option value="13" data-animal_class="1">Bear</option>
  <option value="21" data-animal_class="2">Parrot</option>
  <option value="22" data-animal_class="2">Pigeons</option>
  <option value="23" data-animal_class="2">Bear</option>
  <option value="31" data-animal_class="3">Crocodile</option>
  <option value="32" data-animal_class="3">Lizard</option>
  <option value="33" data-animal_class="3">Turtle</option>
</select>
```