# How to refresh a div without losing the style and plugin (select2) using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel

In the HTML I am trying to reload this div below;

```
           <select name="test[]" id="test" multiple required
                   class="select2">
               @foreach($tests as $s)
                     <option value="{{ $s->id }}" {{ ( in_array($s->id, $tests) ) ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}>
                             {{ $s->value }}
                      </option>
                @endforeach
           </select>
```

I am using a script to reload the content but losing the select2 functionality for the div
here is the snippet I am using to refresh the tag

```
 $( "#test12" ).load(window.location.href + " #test" );
```

Comment: `$('#test12').trigger('change'); ` according to [official docs](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#selecting-options)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to refresh Select2 dropdown menu after ajax loading different content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17818210/how-to-refresh-select2-dropdown-menu-after-ajax-loading-different-content)

Comment: it refreshes the div but doesn't show the updated list with the new content created @Tithira

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to re-initiate the select2 plugin after every refresh of your div element.

because select2 gets bind via script once you called **.select2()** on your select tag, and whenever you refresh the div element in which your select tag is there, the binding will be removed, and it will became normal default select dropdown. So for binding it again you have to  rebind it.

You can try these ways to do it.
**$("#test").select2();**
or
**$("#test").select2("refresh");**