# Select2 update tags content

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-select2

i'm actually using select2 on my form
This is an update form that I display by opening a modal when I click on "update"

The entity "survey" can have between 1 and 6 motivations. The motivations are displayed on the select2 input with tags.

My goal is to update the textual value of the tags only by assigning them a precise value according to their current value. I dont want to update the options values.

I'm currently looping on the tags, everything seems working. When I console.log in the loop it does update the tag but nothing happens on the screen :(

Is there a way that select2 detects the opening of the form (and not the opening of the select on click) ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var select2Input = $('#appbundle_survey_motivations');
  var motivationTagsLibelles = {};

  select2Input.select2();

  var motivationTags = select2Input.next('.select2-container').find('.select2-selection__choice');

  var data = select2Input.select2('data');

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(data, function(singleData) {
    var id = singleData.id;
    var title = singleData.title;
    var libelle = motivationArray[id];
    motivationTagsLibelles[id] = libelle;
  });

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(motivationTags, function(singleTag) {
    var title = singleTag.title;
    var firstChar = title[0];
    var targetValue = null;

    for (const key in motivationTagsLibelles) {
      if (motivationTagsLibelles[key].startsWith(firstChar)) {
        targetValue = motivationTagsLibelles[key];
        break;
      }
    }

    singleTag.innerText = targetValue;
  });
});
```

Comment: Looks to me like all you are doing there is manipulate stuff in an array you are looping over. Not sure what part of this is actually supposed to make select2 go over the already existing HTML structure, and update anything in there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how could I do to update the HTML structure by just opening the form ? It doesn't seem to me that select2 handles this kind of event

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/q/16480910/1427878 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/17818210/1427878 can help with some insight here.