# Select2 minimumInputLength Not Working After append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

In my select2, I use minimumInputLength option to start filtering after a certain length.

```
selectExample.select2({
  minimumInputLength: 2
});
```

But after dynamically append new option with append() function, this minimumInputLength option is not working.

```
selectExample.append('<option value="10">Ten</option>');
```

What happened exactly? Is there a specific way to append new option for select2?

The current solution I use is redeclaring the .select2() with the minimumInputLength option included.

Comment: Have a look here: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/17348414/4202224](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17348414/4202224) or look at the `data`-option of select2

Answer (score 0):

```
var dynamicOptions=[{ id: 0, text: 'enhancement' }, { id: 1, text: 'bug' }, { id: 2, text: 'duplicate' }, { id: 3, text: 'invalid' }, { id: 4, text: 'wontfix' }];

 $("#select2").select2('data', dynamicOptions);
```

this is how you need to add options

Comment: How do you add attributes to the option html? For example, I want to add data-filename attribute to the select option.

Comment: Tried your solution, still need to redeclaring the select2 with minimumInputLength.