# How to reset the data after init , Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I use [Select2-4.0.0](https://select2.github.io/) I have been struggling with this problem for a whole day that to update the data.

I search every posts I can like [Update select2 data without rebuilding the control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16480910/update-select2-data-without-rebuilding-the-control), but none have them work.

What I need is really simple (a setter to data):

I have a diaglog, which had a select. Every time I open the diaglog, I will ajax for an data to keep it in a local array like:

when dialog open :

```
    var select2List=syncToLoadTheData();//data for select2
    $('#search-user-select').select2({  //here when secondly executed, the select2's data on UI does not refreshed 
        data:select2List,
        matcher: function(params, data){
            var key = params.term;
            if ($.trim(key) === '') {
                return data;
            }
            if( (matchKeyAndPinyin(key,data.text))){
                return data;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But the problem is even though the list is changing, the select options does not change at all.Please note in my test case, every time i open the dialog, the data from server is changed:

What I had tried:
1.when init:

```
  data: function() { return {results: select2List}; }// not work to show any data at all
```

2.when secondly open dialog:

```
  $( "#search-user-select").select2('data',newdata,true);//not work to have the new data
```

3.when secondly open:

```
   $("#search-user-select").select2("updateResults");//Error, does not have this method
```

And some other method like directly change the array's data(only one copy of the data), but none of them work.

Comment: You might need to call `select2("destroy")` before re-initializing it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/h2xpebgx/2/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before, my problem was i need to update the select2 after every ajax request with new data.

and this how i fixed my code.

```
         EventId = $(this).attr('id');


           $.ajax({
            url: 'AjaxGetAllEventPerons',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {id: EventId},
        })
        .done(function(data) {


                $("#select2_job").select2({
                minimumInputLength: 2,
                multiple:true,

                initSelection : function (element, callback) {
                //var data = data;



                callback(data);
                },

                ajax: {
                url: "/AjaxGetAllPersonForEvent",
                dataType: 'json',
                quietMillis: 100,
                data: function (term) {
                    return {
                        term: term
                    };
                },
                results: function (data) {
                    var myResults = [];
                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        myResults.push({
                            'id': item.id,
                            'text': item.fullname
                        });
                    });
                    return {
                        results: myResults
                    };
                }
                }
                });
```

I hope this example will help you to solve your problem