# How to dynamically update select source data

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have two select inputs, the first one has a list of options and based on what's selected, the 2nd select will change it's data.  Initially, the 2nd select will have no values but it will dynamically change as the user selects values from the 1st select.

```
var sounds = {
                0:[{'id':0, 'text':'woof'}, {'id':1, 'text':'bark'}],
                1:[{'id':0, 'text':'meow'}, {'id':1, 'text':'purr'}],
                2:[{'id':0, 'text':'moo'}, {'id':1, 'text':'bellow'}]
             };
$('#select1').select2({
    data: [
               {'id':0, 'text':'DOG'},
               {'id':1, 'text':'CAT'},
               {'id':2, 'text':'COW'}
          ]
});
var select2_data = []
$('#select2').select2({
    data: select2_data
});

$('#select1').on("change", function(e) {
    data = $(this).select2('data');
    // Why doesn't this change data: in select2
    select2_data = sounds[data.id]
    $.each(select2_data, function(i, val) {
        console.log(val)
    });
});
```

In order to change select2's data, I assign the new list which data: is pointing to, but this doesn't work.  I am still seeing empty values.  What's going on?

Comment: but you don't reassign just printing it in console. Did you check the console?

Comment: select2 version used?

Comment: You may find this post helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16480910/update-select2-data-without-rebuilding-the-control

Comment: I am reassigning it here: select2_data = sounds[data.id]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this would solve this problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/r7dhxt8e/6/

The only way to dynamically update to select2 is update `select` element options, `select2` will listen for the changes and it will update it automatically.

```
    $(function() {
    var select1, select2, sounds, select2data = [];
    select1 = $("#select1"), select2 = $("#select2");
    sounds = { 0:[{'id':0, 'text':'woof'}, {'id':1, 'text':'bark'}],
              1:[{'id':0, 'text':'meow'}, {'id':1, 'text':'purr'}],
              2:[{'id':0, 'text':'moo'}, {'id':1, 'text':'bellow'}]
    };

    select1.select2({
        data:[
               {'id':0, 'text':'DOG'},
               {'id':1, 'text':'CAT'},
               {'id':2, 'text':'COW'}
          ],
        width:"200px"
    });
    select2.select2({
        data:select2data,
        width: "200px"
    });

    select1.on("change", function(e) {
       var data = $(this).select2('data');
       select2data = data && sounds[data[0].id];
       setSelect2Options(select2data);
    });

    function setSelect2Options(data) {
       if(!data) return;
       var i, l, html, opt;
       for(i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
           opt = data[i];
           html += "<option value='"+ opt.id+"'>"+ opt.text + "</option>";
       }
       if(html) {
           select2.html(html);
       }
       select2.trigger('change');
    }
});
```