# Yii2 How to remove selected value from Select2 of a dynamic form?

Tags: javascript, php, yii2, dynamic-forms

I created a dynamic form using `wbraganca / yii2-dynamicform` to handle requests in my solution. I have couple fields like Item, Qty and Unit. I have a list of items loaded using `ArrayHelper` and I am using `Kartik's Select2` widget to load the data.

`_form.php`

```
<?php

use backend\models\Item;
use backend\models\ItemCategory;
use backend\models\ItemUnit;
use backend\models\Jobs;
use common\models\User;
use kartik\depdrop\DepDrop;
use kartik\select2\Select2;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use wbraganca\dynamicform\DynamicFormWidget;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model backend\models\Requests */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */

$js = '
jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterInsert", function(e, item) {
    jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper .panel-title-address").each(function(index) {
        var i = index;
    });
});

jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("afterDelete", function(e) {
    jQuery(".dynamicform_wrapper .panel-title-address").each(function(index) {
    });
});
';

$this->registerJs($js);

$itemCategory = ItemCategory::find()->where(['cat_status' => 'Active'])->all();
$catData = ArrayHelper::map($itemCategory, 'cat_id', 'cat_name');

if (!Yii::$app->user->identity->isAdmin) {
    $modelJobs = Jobs::find()
        ->joinWith('myJobs')
        ->where(['ja_user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id, 'ja_status' => 'Active'])
        ->all();
} else {
    $modelJobs = Jobs::find()
        ->where(['job_status' => 'In Progress'])
        ->all();
}

$jobs = ArrayHelper::map($modelJobs, 'job_id', function ($modelJobs) {
    return $modelJobs->job_no . '-' . $modelJobs->getJobTitle($modelJobs->job_invt_no);
});
if (isset($_GET['cid'])) {
    $cat_id = $_GET['cid'];
    $subCate = Item::find()->where(['item_category' => $cat_id, 'item_status' => 'Active'])->all();
    $invListData = ArrayHelper::map($subCate, 'item_id', 'item_title');
} else {
    $cat_id = '';
    $invListData = [];
}
if (isset($_GET['job']) && $_GET['job'] != null) {
    $job_id = $_GET['job'];
    $modelJobs = Jobs::find()->where(['job_id' => $job_id])->one();
    $job = $modelJobs->job_no . '-' . $modelJobs->getJobTitle($modelJobs->job_invt_no);
} else {
    $job_id = '';
}
$modelUnit = ItemUnit::find()->where(['unit_status' => 'Active'])->all();
$unit = ArrayHelper::map($modelUnit, 'unit_id', function ($modelUnit) {
    return  $modelUnit->unit_name . '(' . $modelUnit->unit_short_name . ')';
});
?>

<div class="requests-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'dynamic-form']); ?>
    <?php $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?php echo $form->field($model, 'rq_cat_type')->widget(Select2::class, [
                'data' => $catData,
                'options' => ['placeholder' => '--Select Material Category--', 'value' => $cat_id, 'class' => 'form-control'],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true
                ],
                'pluginEvents' => [
                    "select2:select" =>  "function(params) {  
                        console.log($(this).val()); 
                         window.history.pushState('', '', '" . Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('requests/create?job=' . $job_id . '&cid=') . "'+$(this).val());
                         window.location.replace('', '', '" . Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl('requests/create?job=' . $job_id . '&cid=') . "'+$(this).val());
                          jQuery.pjax.reload({ container: '#loaderPjax', async: false });
                 }",
                ],
            ]);
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?php if (isset($_GET['job']) && $_GET['job'] != null) { ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, "rq_job_no")->dropDownList([$job_id => $job], ['value' => $job_id]) ?>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <?php echo $form->field($model, 'rq_job_no')->widget(Select2::class, [
                    'data' => $jobs,
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => '--Select Request Type--', 'class' => 'form-control'],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'allowClear' => true
                    ],
                ]); ?>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'rq_req_date')->widget(\yii\jui\DatePicker::class, [
                //'language' => 'ru',
                'dateFormat' => 'php:Y-m-d',
                'clientOptions' => [
                    'changeMonth' => true,
                    'changeYear' => true,
                    'showButtonPanel' => true,
                    'yearRange' => '1990:2030',
                    'minDate' => date('Y-m-d'),
                ],
                'options' => ['class' => 'form-control', 'readOnly' => true, 'placeholder' => 'Enter the Item Required Date'],
            ]) ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'rq_priority_type')->dropDownList(['Urgent' => 'Urgent', 'Normal' => 'Normal'], ['prompt' => '--Select Priority Type--']) ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'rq_approval_type')->dropDownList([1 => 'Aramco Approved Vendor Needed', 2 => 'Approved Aramco Submitted Needed', 3 => 'Warranty Certificate to be Collected', 4 => 'Long Lead Material',], ['prompt' => '--Select Type of Approval--']) ?>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- code for dynamic form -->
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i> Request Items</h4>
        </div>
        <?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'loaderPjax']); ?>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
                'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper', // required: only alphanumeric characters plus "_" [A-Za-z0-9_]
                'widgetBody' => '.container-items', // required: css class selector
                'widgetItem' => '.item', // required: css class
                'limit' => 10, // the maximum times, an element can be cloned (default 999)
                'min' => 1, // 0 or 1 (default 1)
                'insertButton' => '.add-item', // css class
                'deleteButton' => '.remove-item', // css class
                'model' => $modelsAddress[0],
                'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
                'formFields' => [
                    'rt_item',
                    'rt_qty',
                    'rt_unit',
                ],
            ]); ?>

            <div class="container-items">
                <!-- widgetContainer -->
                <?php foreach ($modelsAddress as $i => $modelAddress) { ?>
                    <div class="item panel panel-default">
                        <!-- widgetBody -->
                        <div class="panel-heading">

                            <h4 class="panel-title pull-left"></h4>
                            <span class="panel-title-address"></span>
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <button type="button" class="add-item btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                                <button type="button" class="remove-item btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <?php
                            // necessary for update action.
                            if (!$modelAddress->isNewRecord) {
                                echo Html::activeHiddenInput($modelAddress, "[{$i}]rt_id");
                            }
                            ?>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <?php echo $form->field($modelAddress, "[{$i}]rt_item")->widget(Select2::class, [
                                        'data' => $invListData,
                                        'options' => ['placeholder' => '--Select Request Type--', 'class' => 'reqItem form-control'],
                                        'pluginOptions' => [
                                            'allowClear' => true
                                        ],
                                    ]); ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <?= $form->field($modelAddress, "[{$i}]rt_qty")->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <?= $form->field($modelAddress, "[{$i}]rt_unit")->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'readOnly' => 'true']) ?>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- .row -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <?php DynamicFormWidget::end(); ?>
        </div>
        <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'rq_remarks')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
<script>
    $(document).on("change", ".reqItem", function() {
        var itemVal = $(this).val();
        var attrID = $(this).attr("id").replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
        $.ajax({
            "url": "units",
            "type": "post",
            "data": {
                itemID: itemVal
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(attrID);
                $("#reqitems-" + attrID + "-rt_unit").val(data);
            },
            error: function(errormessage) {
                //do something else
                alert("not working");

            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The form is working perfectly, But I am facing some issues with the new requirement. The updated is to remove the selected value from the list. Which means if I select a value from the dropdown, the list should be updated without the selected value for next index in the dynamic form.

[image]

Tried couple of solutions with JQuery and javascript. The goal of requirement is to avoid duplicate entry of same value. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: You can clear select2 in `afterInsert` event.

Comment: The value in select2 is loaded using ArrayHelper with condition. So I am confused how to pass it dynamically.

Comment: You can set selected items ids in session and pass thous ids to your model  function which will return the results without ids. Just check if the items are selected before to call the list.

Comment: Scan previously added select2 values and in `afterInsert` set the options for select2.

Comment: @InsaneSkull Can you please help me with any reference?

Comment: [Reference Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30092947/how-to-dynamically-update-select-source-data). I can help but it will take some time to create the example.