# Update select2 values

Tags: jquery-select2

How would I approach updating the values of a select2 drop-down?

I've looked here already and nothing I tested did updated the replaced the data in the drop-down. - [Update select2 data without rebuilding the control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16480910/update-select2-data-without-rebuilding-the-control)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the sub-par writing, I wrote this while I was tired. However I noticed there was no question/answer anywhere for this topic, I eventually got it.

I feel like a bit of a schlub for not figuring this out sooner.

```
$('#element').select2().empty(); // empty the select2
$('#element').select2({ placeholder: 'Select A Model', data: data }); // fill the existing select2 with the data
```