# ASP.NET MVC Multiple selection listbox values not rendering

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 single select drop-downs and 1 multi-select list-box. following is the code in html.I have first selected the value from first drop-down(single select). according to its value second drop-down values were loaded.Then I selected a value from 2nd drop-down.Ideal scenario is according to 2nd drop-down value 3rd multi-select list-box should be loaded with value.I have encountered a strange behavior. Even though in HTML select is showing option values, But when rendering it shows No Results.

```
 <div class="row sub-container">
            <div class="sub-heading">Filter supplier / service provider by categories</div>

            <div class="form-group clearfix">
                <label class="form-label col-md-3">Services Categories Level 1</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <section id="section-examples" class="attireBlock mod1">
                        <div class="">
                            <div class="">
                                @Html.DropDownList("addServiceServiceCategoryLevel1", Model.ServiceCategoryList, "Please select a Category", new { @class = "form-control" })
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group clearfix">
                <label class="form-label col-md-3">Services Category Level2</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <section id="section-examples" class="attireBlock mod1">
                        <div class="">
                            @Html.DropDownList("addServiceServiceCategoryLevel2", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Id", "Name"), "Please select a Category", new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group clearfix">
                <label class="form-label col-md-3">Services Category</label>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <section id="section-examples" class="attireBlock mod1">
                        
                        <div class="fstElement fstMultipleMode fstNoneSelected">
                          

                            @Html.ListBox("addServiceServiceCategory",new SelectList(string.Empty, "Id", "Name"), new { @class = "multipleSelect", @multiple = "" })
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>

 $(document).ready(function () {

               $('.multipleSelect').fastselect();


  $("#addServiceServiceCategoryLevel2").on("change", function () {  // whenever a selection is made
        $("#addServiceServiceCategory").empty();

        var id = $("#addServiceServiceCategoryLevel2").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', // we are calling json method
            url: "/ServiceProviders/GetServiceCategoryLevel2",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { id },
            success: function (states) {

                $.each(states, function (i, state) {
                    $("#addServiceServiceCategory").append('<option value="' + state.Value + '">' +
                        state.Text + '</option>');
                });
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

});

[image]

Comment: are you using any js plugin on your 3rd multi select?

Comment: yes. fastselect    http://dbrekalo.github.io/fastselect/

Comment: you did not show how you are filling the 3rd multi select, but presumably using $.ajax - > try re initialize your 3rd multi select with your js plugin when ajax update

Comment: @Alan Tsai, Thanks for your feed back. I have updated the relevant code.. please check

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is because you are updating your options **after** you initialize as `fastselect`

hence it did not pick up the new change

try re initialize once ajax success load data

so something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', // we are calling json method
    url: "/ServiceProviders/GetServiceCategoryLevel2",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { id },
    success: function (states) {

        $.each(states, function (i, state) {
            $("#addServiceServiceCategory").append('<option value="' + state.Value + '">' +
                state.Text + '</option>');
        });

        // re initalize fastselect`
        $('.multipleSelect').fastselect();
    },
    error: function (ex) {
        alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Alan, after changed like above code, still it shows as no result. But before changing the code,initially  i got the values in drop-down. But after changing the code, even first time also i didn't get the values in drop-down.it didn't work for me..

Comment: I probably have to run localy to give a test.  But honestly have you consider use other plugin? this one seem not really active.  IHO I would recommend select2 http://select2.github.io/examples.html - you could achieve what you want easily with different way, one way is by using local array and then updating array with ajax later. more info checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/17348414/2564920

Comment: thanks @Alan.. Yes it may be bug in plugin..  will check Select2 also..

Comment: @AslamJiffry personally I would make the switch. saw a issue on `fastsearch` (which is a base plugin to the one you used) where someone said not possible to add option dynamically https://github.com/dbrekalo/fastsearch/issues/2 .  I can not find how to destroy and re init `fastselect` so I think it may be easier to just make switch