# how to set default value of select 2 box in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to set default value of select 2 box in JavaScript.
I have an API from where updated value comes, I need to update select box

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update select2 data without rebuilding the control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16480910/update-select2-data-without-rebuilding-the-control)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$('#ID').select2("val", "stringValue");

stringValue you are setting should be available in select options.