# How to add an additional selection in select2 multi select dropdown programmatically without losing the existing selected items

Tags: javascript, forms, jquery-select2

I have a scenario like whenever a user selects a particular "State" in the multi-select select2 dropdown another state has to be automatically selected.

For example, if the user selects State 'A' then state 'C' also has to be selected. The logic is A & C always go together.

I am looking for an option to do this, currently, I am capturing `select2:select` event and checking the selected item is A or C, if so then getting all the selected items using

```
select2Object.select2('data')
```

Then loop through the items and getting the Value and then appending the value of state 'C' and then triggering the change event.

Is there any direct way to do this? For example, if I go with

```
select2Object.val("C"); 
select2Object.trigger('change');
```

this code then it will clear all other selections and select only the state 'C'. I am looking for a solution to add a new selection item without losing the old selected items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be pretty straightforward. All you need to do is save the existing selections, push the new value, and trigger the change event. So for your case this should work:

```
// get all selected options (including the one you just selected)
let data = select2Object.val();

/* some logic that determines 'C' should be added */
data.push('C');
select2Object.val(data).trigger('change');
```

Comment: sorry , the answer you mentioned here is already there in my try list. I am looking for a direct approach. seems like select2 doesnt have a direct approach for doing this

Comment: You might want to look at my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64252695/1307183 which contains a generic reusable function that allows you to do what you're looking for, but yes the `select2` library does not explicitly have the exact functionality you are looking for.

Comment: You are right. working directly on the <select> element do the trick. Thanks for the answer

Comment: No problem - I like that select2 tries to maintain itself more as a display wrapper on top of your existing `<select>` elements, so you can still submit forms and work directly on those DOM elements without having to worry about special code that depends on the select2 library.