# Programmatically trigger request/reload for jQuery ajax-chosen

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using ajax-chosen for dynamically populated list with keyword search.
The option list values depend on a radio button.
I would like to trigger the ajax-chosen list request upon radio button change.
how do I trigger reload (not chosen:updaed) programmatically to perform ajax request and re-populate the list with new values depend on the radio selection ?
I do have the radio value as part of the request, however triggering the ajax request reload is missing.

Project link:
https://github.com/ksykulev/chosen-ajax-addition

Comment: Neither the Chosen library nor its AJAX extension which you linked to provide any method of 'refreshing' the AJAX data used to display the options. If you require this behaviour you would need to create it yourself, ie. by destroying the original Chosen instance, and creating a new one to make another AJAX request

Comment: Note that the Select2 library does have this functionality available. I'd suggest using that instead if you need this behaviour: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17348414/519413

Comment: Can I extend ajax-chosen with refresh functionality ?

Comment: Sure, but it's a very outdated library. I'd suggest just using Select2 as it has exactly what you need, and is kept up to date