# Change Selected Value in a Select HTML Element with DOM Button Click in select2.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with changing selected value directly with a button click.

First, when I use these codes below without select2.js it works just fine.

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="1">Ana</option>
  <option value="2">Lisa</option>
  <option value="3">Jeremy</option>
  <option value="4">August</option>
</select>

<button type="button" onclick="changeValue()">Chose August</button>


<script>
      function changeValue() {
      document.getElementById("mySelect").value = "4";
      }
</script>
```

As you know, that button makes "August" as the selected value. But when I use select2.js, it doesn't work. I use select2.js to change other dropdowns options.

Please help. Thanks for advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13268083/select2-changing-items-dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `val` method of select2.js

```
$('#mySelect').select2("val", 4)
```