# Select2 Change Event - Change the options for next select2 box on first select2 box value change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have 2 `select2` boxes. First is Category and next is Sub-category.

Now, I want to change the options for subcategory box based on Category box selected value. And the data for Subcategory box should load using AJAX.

Please help me.

Comment: you can take some ideas from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13268083/select2-changing-items-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

just solved it myself

```
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<select class="js-data-example-ajax" id="category" >
<option value="">Select a category</option>
<option>cat1</option>
<option>cat2</option>
<option>cat3</option>
</select>
<select class="js-data-example-ajax" id="sub-category" >
</select>
<script>
  $("#category").select2({
  placeholder: "Select a category",allowClear: true
  });

  $("#sub-category").select2({
  placeholder: "Select sub-category",allowClear: true
  });


  $('#category').on("change", function (e) { 
   var result = '';
   var catval = $(this).val();
    if(catval != '') {
     url = "subcats_top/"+ catval;
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
        var length = data.length;

        if(length > 0) {
            for(key in data) {
                result += '<option value="' + data[key].id + '">' + data[key].name + '</option>';
            }


        } else {

        }
        $("#sub-category").html(result);
    }
    });
  }
   });
    </script>
```

Comment: are you sure there is nothing more elegant?