# yii2 kartik select2 plugin doesnt work in modal

Tags: jquery, yii2, bootstrap-modal, jquery-select2

The dropdown doesnot appear when I try to use [kartik select2](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2) plugin in modal. It works like charm when I use it without modal.
This the same code taken from the plugin website, But it still doesn't work. I have found in the source code generated by the browser that select2 plugin css and js are not been loaded from assets folder

This is how the HTML looks
[image]

```
   Modal::begin([

    'header' => '<h1>Assign Applicant</h1>',
    'options' => [
        'id' => 'assignApplicantModal',
        'tabindex' => false
    ],
]);
?>


<div class="job-positions-form">

    <?php
    $form = ActiveForm::begin();
    ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="col-sm-6">

                <?php
                $data = ArrayHelper::map(Applicant::find()->where('status = :status', [':status' => 'Active'])->all(), 'id', function($model) {
                            return $model->first_name . ' ' . $model->last_name;
                        });

                echo $form->field($assign_model, 'applicant_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                    'data' => $data,
                    'attribute' => 'applicant_id',
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select an applicant'],
                    'pluginEvents' => [
                        "select2:selecting" => "function() { "
                        . "no_position = $('body').data('no_position');"
                        . "if(no_position>= " . $model->no_of_persons . "){alert('You can select only " . $model->no_of_persons . " applicant(s)');return false;}  }",
                        "select2:select" => "function() { "
                        . "no_position = $('body').data('no_position');"
                        . "$('body').data('no_position',++no_position);}",
                        "select2:unselect" => "function() { "
                        . "no_position = $('body').data('no_position');"
                        . "$('body').data('no_position',--no_position);}",
                    ]
                ]);
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?php echo $form->field($assign_model, 'applicant_pay')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center;">
                <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
<?php
$inlineScript = "$('body').data('no_position'," . count($applicant_id) . ")";
$this->registerJs($inlineScript, \yii\web\View::POS_END, 'my-inline-js');
Modal::end();
```

HTML taken from browser:

```
<div id="assignApplicantModal" class="fade modal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog ">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
<h1>Assign Applicant</h1>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">


<div class="job-positions-form">

    <form id="w0" action="/staffing/scheduler/web/scheduler/assign_applicant" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_schedulerCSRF" value="eEI4TnpSZWcaFnYWNQQcKx0ndC8VEVUyDAl6LAgfBzUTKQw3EBAEEg
==">    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="col-sm-6">

                <div class="form-group field-assignapplicant-applicant_id required">
<label class="control-label" for="assignapplicant-applicant_id">Applicant</label>
<div class="kv-plugin-loading loading-assignapplicant-applicant_id">&nbsp;</div><select id="assignapplicant-applicant_id"
 class="form-control" name="AssignApplicant[applicant_id]" data-s2-options="s2options_d6851687" data-krajee-select2
="select2_86691c6a" style="display:none">
<option value="">Select an applicant</option>
<option value="12">ASD</option>
<option value="13">qwe</option>
<option value="14">zxc</option>
</select>

<div class="help-block"></div>
</div>            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group field-assignapplicant-applicant_pay required">
<label class="control-label" for="assignapplicant-applicant_pay">Applicant Pay</label>
<input type="text" id="assignapplicant-applicant_pay" class="form-control" name="AssignApplicant[applicant_pay
]">

<div class="help-block"></div>
</div>            </div>

            <div class="form-group" style="text-align: center;">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form></div>

</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check how the output html looks like?

Comment: @Dekel I have placed the image of the HTML. please check

Comment: We don't need the image, we need the html. It's impossible to know how the html code looks by looking at an image :)

Comment: @Dekel The code already have HTML. check   echo $form->field($assign_model, 'applicant_id')->widget(Select2. this link generate HTML

Comment: I'm sorry but `$form->field($assig` is PHP code, and not **output html** read again my comment and add the FINAL HTML OUTPUT. Otherwise it's really hard to help.

Comment: @Dekel updated the HTML taken from the browser

Comment: And now, when you have the `html` - you can see that you have there a `style="display:none"`

Comment: :))) @Dekel this is browser generated HTML. Hope you know that it is always display none. Please check plugin and several other extension which is build upon basic html. the plugin will add its html on top of it and so it hide the main html.

Comment: Did you get this HTML using view-source or using inspect-element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When content of the modal is dynamic, Select2 assets will not be loaded because initially there is no Select2 related code in DOM.

**1)** You can register Select2 assets in advance by calling:

```
\kartik\select2\Select2Asset::register($this);
```

And then you need to initialize Select2 on every modal content change by calling something like:

```
$('#field-id').select2();
```

**2)** Instead of replacing all HTML inside modal, just render it in advance including empty select (or with some initial data) and only change data inside of it after clicking on different modal triggers.

See this related SO questions:

- [Update select2 data without rebuilding the control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16480910/update-select2-data-without-rebuilding-the-control)
- [select2 changing items dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13268083/select2-changing-items-dynamically)

And according [Select2 issue](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2830).

The way I used last time:

```
$dependentDropdown.find('option:not([value=""])').remove();
$dependentDropdown.select2('val', '');
// This can come from AJAX request
var data = [
    {'id': 1, 'text': 'Some text 1'},
    {'id': 2, 'text': 'Some text 2'}
],
var html = '';
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    html += '<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.text + '</option>';
});
$dependentDropdown.append(html);
```

Answer (score 2):

In **yii\bootstrap\Modal** the `tabindex="-1"` option prevents **Select2** search input from working.

A simple fix could be to remove the tabindex option.

*With JQuery:* `$('#id_of_the_modal').removeAttr('tabindex');`

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I used `$this->render()` in the controller action that renders the content of my fancybox modal window, and I should have used `$this->renderAjax()`. NOw it displays the select properly.

Answer (score 0):

Worked at my side

```
body .select2-container {
  z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```