# Multi-select add/remove select in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a form I've two multi-select. I can add items from select1 to select2 or remove items from select2 using the following jquery functions:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
   function addProject() {    
      return !$('#select1 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select2');
   }

   function removeProject() {
      return !$('#select2 option:selected').remove().appendTo('#select1');
   }
</script>

<select multiple id="select1" class="form-control">
@for(p <- projects) {
    option value="@p.getName">@p.getName</option>
}
</select>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  onclick="addProject();" >
   <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  onclick="removeProject();" >
   <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-minus'></span>
</button>

<select name="projects" multiple id="select2" class="form-control">
</select>
```

The problem is that if I add items to select2 and submit the form I receive all values. If I add and remove items or vice-versa I don't receive values.

I tried to add another jquery function to select all items inside select2 before submit the form but didn't work.

```
function select_projects() {
    $('#select2').children('option').attr('selected', 'selected');
}
```

How can solve the problem?

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13268083/select2-changing-items-dynamically

Comment: I checked but don't seems related to my problem.

Comment: Like said in this answer, you need to call the `.select2()` function again when you want to cahnge the items of your select.

Comment: Ok, but my functions seems to works fine. I can add/remove items without problem. The problem born when I submit the form

Comment: When I remove an item from select2, the selection remains on this item and when I submit the form the select2 has no item selected

Comment: I solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved changing the select_projects() function like follow:

```
function select_projects() {
    $('#select1 option:selected').attr('selected', false);
    $('#select2').children().prop('selected', true);
}
```